# Facebook App is not working in Chrome but well in Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, firefox, heroku

I have just started making Facebook Apps using heroku. I made a test app. I uploaded a page on heroku which uses HTML5, CSS and Javascript. The app is not showing in Google Chrome https://apps.facebook.com/shrytestapp/ but works well in Mozilla Firefox. Also, the page works well when opened in heroku server http://salty-shelf-6707.herokuapp.com/.

Answer (score 5):

When you access the app within Facebook, HTTPS is used to transfer the data, but Chrome has blocked content delivered over normal HTTP as a result and insists that everything be transfered securely whereas Firefox isn't so fussy.

Here's what the Console is showing in Chrome

```
[blocked] The page at https://salty-shelf-6707.herokuapp.com/
    ran insecure content from http://www.google.com/jsapi.
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Google's JS API has been blocked and the JavaScript fails to run.

(You also have some not found errors, but that's unrelated)

The app works fine through the http://salty-shelf-6707.herokuapp.com/ as you mentioned, but not through https://salty-shelf-6707.herokuapp.com/

Try using the following instead to load the API

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

the `//` at the start of the src value will make the url protocol-relative or for the correct technical term, scheme-relative.

Paul Irish, the lead developer of HTML5 Boilerplate, [has more information about this in a post on his site.](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

Comment: Thank you @Adam-E ... This should be marked as the right answer!